Random brightness/contrast/color with a very smooth transition (to make a ground texture)
I have a big highly detailed green picture that I want to use as a texture for an island:

I would like to make it more varied, so it does not look so monotonous, but I want to save this highly detailed texture (ornament) without loss of quality.
Experimentally I found the following way to do something like that using Photoshop. I select an area using the lasso tool, then right click, "Feather", set 1000 pixels for the feather radius. I repeat the "Feather" procedure several times, because I can not set more than 1000 pixels at once. Then I go "Image" > "Adjusnments" > "Photo Filter". I set the color like brown and increase the density to have a slightly different tone (color). I make several such selections with different colors. Also, these selections overlap each other. For example, I get the following:

I am actually pleased with this result. I just need to make more of these selections (and make them smaller). But maybe there is any better way to get the similar result faster, with more randomization and smaller selected areas.
So, I would like to get a texture for an island that would have green, brown, yellow colors of different shades that would smoothly transition into each other while saving the texture (namely by changing brightness, contrast, color). I just feel like there might be a better way (algorithm) to do such the thing in Photoshop.
A way with clouds:


I'm a believe in using my cell phone.... I'd simply take a photo of a real texture I found and liked. There is often little need to try and fabricate something so it looks natural when you can just photograph something natural.

No exact idea what you want, but try clouds and gradient map.

I have an RGB image, the foreground color is white, the BG color is black, applied Filter > Render > Clouds. In the shown image the brightness scale is stretched with curves to cover the whole range from black to white.
It may be useful to apply few px Gaussian Blur to fade the brightness banding that is caused by the scale stretching. I skipped it.
In the next image a gradient map is applied (sorry for moving the clouds before applying the gradient map)


Thank you. I tried something like that, although it seems the clouds cover the texture and it is not visible through them.

@misha.physics I guessed that your texture contained 2 different greens and you wanted to colorize with smoothly varying colors the lighter green areas. I didn't try to reuse your texture image. My clouds  create new same style areas. Move the leftmost gradient stop a little rightwards to make the "non-colored" areas bigger.

@misha.physics (continued) But if you want to use your own texture desaturate it, increase its contrast (if needed) and let it have layer.blending mode "Luminosity". Place the  colorized clouds to the bottom. The clouds give hue and saturation, your texture defines the brightness.

Well, I have a picture with two layers. UP - my desaturated texture with increased contrast. DOWN - clouds that I got using Filter - Render - Clouds. I set the luminosity mode for the first layer. But I see only my texture. And the clouds on the second layer aren't coloried. I see the clouds with my texture if I decrease opacity/fill for the first layer. But maybe you meant something else. I added a screenshot to my started post.

@misha.physics Colorize the clouds with the gradient map. Then add the luminosity defining layer.

Thanks, I've done something I wanted.
